# Slicing a string in a loop through a Pandas DataFame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to a slice a string in a column of a Pandas DataFrame in a loop and return that substring as a new column. This approach is working just fine:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    new_list.append(df.iloc[i]['columnA'][10:20])
df['new_column'] = new_list
```

**Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?** Curious about alternative approaches to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
df['new_column'] = df['columnA'].str[10:20]
```

Comment: For a DataFrame with ~120,000 rows, your approach is >300 times faster than my function (0.038 seconds vs. 11.46 seconds). Thank you.